# Order statistics that are iid random variables

Tags: statistics

Given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent identically distributed random variables with mean $1$ (exponentially distributed),  find $\text{Prob}(X_2 > 2X_1)$? I'm not sure how to attack this, if you can get me started I'll do the rest.

Comment: Do you have any information about their probability distribution?

Comment: ...'Cause without that, one cannot answer.

Comment: sorry, thery're exponential random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_2$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $1$, then $P(X_2\gt x)=\mathrm e^{-x}$ for every positive $x$, hence 
$$
P(X_2\gt \color{red}{\mathbf 2}X_1)=E(\mathrm e^{-\color{red}{\mathbf 2}X_1}).
$$
Furthermore, for every nonnegative $\color{blue}{\mathbf c}$,
$$
E(\mathrm e^{-\color{blue}{\mathbf c}X_1})=\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-\color{blue}{\mathbf c}x}\,\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx=\frac1{\color{blue}{\mathbf c}+1},
$$
hence
$$
P(X_2\gt \color{red}{\mathbf 2}X_1)=\frac1{\color{red}{\mathbf 2}+1}=\frac13.
$$